# Cannot determine the module for class X in X.ts! Add X to the NgModule to fix it error in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, ionic2-providers

I am facing an issue when I try to build my app using the following command :

`ionic cordova run android --prod --release`

Everything runs fine if I run the command as below:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

The error Iam getting is :

> Error: Cannot determine the module for class CartItemsPage in
>   C:/test/src/pages/cart/cart-items.ts! Add CartItemsPage to the
>   NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class ItemsPage in
>   C:/test/src/pages/items/items.ts! Add ItemsPage to th e NgModule to
>   fix it. Cannot determine the module for class UserHomePage in
>   C:/test/src/pages/user-home/user-home.ts! Add User HomePage to the
>   NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class
>   ForgotPasswordPage in C:/test/src/pages/forgot-password/forgot-pas
>   sword.ts! Add ForgotPasswordPage to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot
>   determine the module for class LoginPage in
>   C:/test/src/pages/login/login.ts! Add LoginPage to th e NgModule to
>   fix it. Cannot determine the module for class SignupPage in
>   C:/test/src/pages/signup/signup.ts! Add SignupPage t o the NgModule to
>   fix it. Cannot determine the module for class WelcomePage in
>   C:/test/src/pages/welcome/welcome.ts! Add WelcomePa ge to the NgModule
>   to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class PincodePage in
>   C:/test/src/pages/pincode/pincode.ts! Add PincodePa ge to the NgModule
>   to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class AppHomePage in
>   C:/test/src/pages/app-home/app-home.ts! Add AppHome Page to the
>   NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class ProfilePage
>   in C:/test/src/pages/profile/profile.ts! Add ProfilePa ge to the
>   NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class
>   OrderDetailPage in C:/test/src/pages/myorders/order-detail.ts! Add 
>   OrderDetailPage to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module
>   for class MyOrdersPage in C:/test/src/pages/myorders/myorders.ts! Add
>   MyOrde rsPage to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module
>   for class LogoutPage in C:/test/src/pages/logout/logout.ts! Add
>   LogoutPage t o the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for
>   class MyApp in C:/test/src/app/app.component.ts! Add MyApp to the
>   NgModu le to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class
>   RemoveUnderscorePipe in C:/test/src/utils/pipes/RemoveUnderscore.t s!
>   Add RemoveUnderscorePipe to the NgModule to fix it.

but I have added all my pages and pipes to app.module.ts as below :

```
// Imports

// The translate loader needs to know where to load i18n files
// in Ionic's static asset pipeline.
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}


let pages:any = [
  MyApp,
  LoginPage,
  UserHomePage,
  SignupPage,
  AppHomePage,
  WelcomePage,
  ItemsPage,
  CartItemsPage,
  ProfilePage,
  MyOrdersPage,
  OrderDetailPage,
  ForgotPasswordPage,
  PincodePage,
  LogoutPage
];

let pipes = [RemoveUnderscorePipe];

export function declarations() {
  return pages.concat(pipes);
}

export function entryComponents() {
  return pages;
}

export function providers() {
  return [
    Api,
    ItemsService,
    UserService,
    ToastService,
    CartService,
    OrdersService,
    TokenService,
    Camera,
    GoogleMaps,
    SplashScreen,
    StatusBar,

    // Keep this to enable Ionic's runtime error handling during development
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ];
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: declarations(),
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [Http]
      }
    }),
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: entryComponents(),
  providers: providers()
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

If u see my app.module.ts, I have added components and pipes to entrycomponents and declarations. Is there anything I am missing for production flag.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This could also be a filename casing problem. see github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10732

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed declarations to pages like below and it worked.

```
declarations: pages
```

I got the answer at :https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-while-running-the-ionic3-app-in-production-mode/106294

Answer (score 16):

This could also be a filename casing problem. see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10732

Comment: This was the solution in my case. 
Kebab-case, camel-case, capital first,... I'm just going slightly mad.

Answer (score 13):

elaborating on answer by @[Thom Kiesewetter]

It could also be a **path casing** issue reference used in the **module** or in **routes** or anywhere else

e.g path was

> import { EmployeeComponent } from "./**E**ntities/employee.component";

instead of

> import { EmployeeComponent } from "./**e**ntities/employee.component";

where the real path was "**e**ntities" and not "**E**ntities"

Comment: Saved my day. I had the exactly problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem , but for me, two components with the same name were there something like below,

**my-first-app\src\app\header\header.component.ts**

**my-first-app\src\header\header.component.ts**

the second one is unused and wrongly placed as all my codes were inside my-first-app\src\app only. I removed the second one and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but for me, two components with the similar name with "s" extra,

**RigDeatilsInfoComponent**

**RigDetailInfoComponent**

We can clearly see here in the first component name I have **details** and the second component name **detail**, still angular is not differentiating between these two.

I solved it by changing one of the component names to **RigGeneralInfoComponent**

Answer (score 0):

Check import path in file it is case sensitive.

Comment: You can send short answers as a comment