# cannot determine the module for component angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm getting following error when I build the Angular app using "ng build --prod". This is working when I build with Angular 4 and getting error with Angular 5. With Angular 5 "ng serve" is working perfectly.

> ERROR in Error: Cannot determine the module for class TimeAgoPipe in mypath/node_modules/time-ago-pipe/time-ago-pipe.ts! Add TimeAgoPipe to the NgModule to fix it.

Getting error for https://www.npmjs.com/package/time-ago-pipe

Any solutions ?

Comment: ensure to add in the declarations array `declarations: [AppComponent, ...etc..., TimeAgoPipe],`

Comment: it is already there... otherwise "ng serve" will give error and build on Angular 4 also will give error... error ONLY on Angular 5

Comment: Can you provide minimal example to reproduce it?

Answer (score 46):

**Check Case Sensitivity**

```
import { MyComponent } from "./User/my-component";
```

In my case, the problem was that the folder **user** was created with *U* as capital in my import statement. But actually, on disk, it was in small-case. When I changed the pathname to **user** (with u lower case) in my import statement, it worked for me.

```
import { MyComponent } from "./user/my-component";
```

**So check the case sensitivity, of your import path.**

Comment: I can't believe it. This case-sensitivity issue happens in Windows also!

Comment: Make sure the actual folder name in windows is lowercase and it won't happen again.

Answer (score 18):

Angular 5 and specifically angular cli 1.5 has default ahead of time compilation turned on and it needs to know module for all components/pipes etc. that it finds in your project folder if you have some components that aren't declared in any module it will throw errors.

You can either declare `TimeAgoPipe` in some module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TimeAgoPipe, ...]
})
export class AppModule {}// for example can be any other used module
```

or try running build without ahead of time compilation **resulting code will work slower**

```
ng build --prod --aot=false
```

third way if you don't use that pipe at all you can add it to excluded files in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  ...
  "exclude": [ "path/to/unused/component.ts", ... ]
}
```

Comment: I had a some unused components (partially built, via copy-n-paste) in my project. I thought they'd be automatically skipped, but instead they were being processed. Worse, the error message failed to mention the file/component where the error was occurring - instead it indicated the component it couldn't find. Turns out my copy-n-paste referenced the "missing" component because I had removed the reference from the pasted module, but not the HTML template.

Comment: We had some mock component classes defined in the shared module under a folder called mocks. These are for testing only so we decided to go with the third option, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

In my case, the error was because of multiple definitions of the same class in various files. This happened due to copy-paste codes by some developer.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same issue and can offer a workaround although not sure why this specific pipe is not being successfully picked up by the aot build:

**Workaround**

Copy the time-ago-pipe.ts from node_modules/time-ago-pipe and just copy this file into your own project.

Add it to your declarations in your module as normal and import this into your imports e.g:

```
import { TimeAgoPipe } from './_pipes/time-ago-pipe';
```

This will then compile successfully in AOT build and you can still use the pipe.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this issue and wanted to consolidate existing suggestions, and suggest some general strategies when nothing else worked for me:

1. In my case, the error was it could not determine the module for a *`Pipe`*; I **was using custom `Pipe` injected straight into an Angular `Service`**.

- When I stopped using the `Pipe`, the issue went away; so I removed the `Pipe` transform  -- I moved the transformation to a different `Service`, stopped depending on `Pipe` altogether.

1. Make sure you **declared** (and exported), your Pipe/Component properly in the `declarations` (and `exports`) properties of your `NgModule`

   - Source: [Angular best practice, `NgModule` basics](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-api#ngmodule-metadata)
2. If it is a 3rd party Pipe/Component (i.e. inside `node_modules`), **copy the Pipe to your own project** (if possible), and/or **re-export** the Pipe from one of your `NgModule`

   - Source: [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47124835/1175496)
3. If you don't *need* the Pipe/Component, you can **exclude** the file by adding to the `exclude` property of the `tsconfig.json` (this may not be an option for everyone)

   - Source: [also accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47124835/1175496)
4. Or build without ahead-of-time compilation `ng build --aot=false` (may be a faster build, but then creates a non-optimized app; learn more about AOT)

   - Source: [Again the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47124835/1175496)
5. If it is *your* Pipe/Component (vs 3rd party), confirm you **don't double-define** your Pipe class, and **don't double-declare** your Pipe: i.e. add to the `declaratations` array of *two or more different* `NgModule`s

   - Source: [Another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52681007/1175496)
6. In your Angular typescript files where you `import { YourPipe } from  './yoUr-pippe.ts'`, make sure there are **no typos or capitalization issues** in your import statement, *especially the filename*

   - (my example here `'./yoUr-pippe.ts'` has a capitalization issue, and a typo, and shouldn't use the `ts` file extension (that's implied in Typescript))
   - Source: [Another answer here,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50475168/1175496) [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51274722/1175496)  [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51274773/1175496), including [this github issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071992/ng-build-prod-cannot-determine-the-module-for-class-x-add-threadlisttabscompo/51274773#51274773)
7. In my case, the above didn't fix my problems. I did many of the steps below, eventually the problem stopped. I'm not sure which one did the trick:

   - Ensure any `ts` file **which *uses*** the problematic Pipe/Component, lives in an `NgModule` **which `import`s the `NgModule` that defined the Pipe/Component**!

     - For example if `AModule`, defines `AComponent`, which uses `BPipe`, defined in `BModule`, then `AModule` must `import` the `BModule`

       - In my case, I re-arranged my `NgModule` dependency tree. I used a ["shared module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576420/how-to-declare-a-pipe-globally-to-use-in-different-modules) pattern so my Pipe could be re-used in multiple places.
   - Ensure there are **no circular `NgModule` dependencies**, like in [these](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/locate-circular-dependencies-in-typescript-modules-2b1eb03dbf2e) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378751/services-depending-on-each-other/49876318#49876318)
   - If you are able, [Upgrade `NodeJS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12313655/1175496) itself and/or `angular` and its tools (`angular-cli`, etc)

     - I ran into unrelated issues, so I found [this list of suggestions](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13734#issuecomment-521743839)... but these suggestions *fixed other issues*, and let me re-approach the `Cannot determine the module...`  issue (which stopped happening!)
   - Be [careful about using `index.ts` files aka "barrel files", and the order of `exports`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53951993/1175496)

     - ([This suggestion may help](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13590#issuecomment-456435939) with `index.ts` file issues)
   - A general problem-solving approach : **Remove / comment-out any references to the problematic file**,

     - Remove the references one-at-a-time, from each file, until your angular app build works. If removing from a specific file solves the problem, you know which file is the source of the problem
     - If you remove the references from *all files* (which may be too hard to do; for me it was not too many/ not too hard); then your angular app should build...
     - Confirm your angular app still builds. In my case, my angular build had unrelated errors which I could easily fix (for example,  `Can't bind to '___' since it isn't a known property of '___'`, or `Property '___' does not exist on type '___'. Did you mean '____'`, or `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`)
     - After fixing any other problems, you can *uncomment* your code gradually, while ensuring your `ng build` works. When I uncommented/added all my code back... my `ng build` no longer had the `Cannot determine the module...` issue

Answer (score 0):

For me it didn't work even when component was there in declarations. So, I removed the component from declarations and from imports as well. And then I readded it by using Visual Studio code intellisense to auto complete component name in declarations and using auto import to import component at the top of the module file. And to my surprise it worked.

If any of the above solutions didn't work for you, then this is also worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import specific component.
2. Add component to @NgModule.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the problem was in case sensitive in import paths. but you must find all imports path that have problem. not only import that used in your module.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a pipe declared as their own class in `mypipe.ts` as well as in `app.component.ts` for some reason. I remove the one in app.component and it compiled fine.

In the error message, check where exactly it is complaining and see if that is double code in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same error only on prod build but not on dev build. I imported component.ts file in app.module.ts but didn't used in NgModule. So I removed the import, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were two components what are named same. I removed one of them and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this error occurred when you created a component but not imported it to any module.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import your component in @NgModule.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error on production build also, with a my class ToastComponent.
I've ended up with not exporting the class (ToastComponent) and use it like so:

```
class ToastComponent extends Toast {
  options: ToastIndividualConfig;
}

interface ToastIndividualConfig extends IndividualConfig {
  template: TemplateRef<any>;
  type: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'template-toast-component',
  templateUrl: './template-toast.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template-toast.component.scss'],
})
export class TemplateToastComponent extends ToastComponent {
```