# Differences between Angular compilations

Tags: angular, aot, angular-aot

When I compile my app with

```
ng build --prod
```

I have this error

```
ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class AppComponent in D:/desarrollos/PatientPortal/front/src/app/customizations/database/app.component-database.ts! Add AppComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
```

but if it compile with

```
ng build --configuration=prod
```

It's compile ok and my app works ok.

I see the difference is the first one is compile with the AOT option, but I don't know why have this error, and don't know if it is important (maybe is about an extended class I have, but is important to me). Can you help me?

Comment: In which module did you declare that `AppComponent`? And don't confuse it with the default `AppComponent`. Maybe show your component declaration from `/app.component-database.ts`

Comment: I have the default AppComponent and duplicate it to use a different app.component.html (need a costumization) and replace it in the angular.json... but I don't declare because one substitute the other

Comment: If just the html changes, try keeping the same component and just substituting the html in `angular.json`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do it, because in this case actually don't use the .ts file, but have other error `ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class BookappointmentsComponent in D:/desarrollos/PatientPortal/front/src/app/customizations/database/bookappointments.page-database.ts! Add BookappointmentsComponent to the NgModule to fix it.` and in this case I use this .ts file

Comment: The problem here is that `BookappointmentsComponent` is not referenced in any NgModule.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119135/cannot-determine-the-module-for-component-angular-5/47124835

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found help In the github repository:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38070

In my case, I'm trying to compile and abstract class using @Component decorator insteed @Directive decorator.

Answer (score 1):

Angular normally complains when you declare a component that is not part of any module.

If you just want to modify the default `AppComponent` html template at build time, you can just create a separate  html template and use `fileReplacements` feature from `angular.json`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do it, because in this case actually don't use the .ts file, but have other error ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class BookappointmentsComponent in D:/desarrollos/PatientPortal/front/src/app/customizations/database/bookappointments.page-database.ts! Add BookappointmentsComponent to the NgModule to fix it. and in this case I use this .ts file –