# Cannot determine the module for class Component in component.ts file, add component to the NgModule to fix it

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-modules

I have a project which uses angular libraries. So for the development of the library, I am using the build command with the `watch` option, so when I make a change to the library code, it will be automatically compiled and built. Then on another tab in the terminal, I am running `ng serve --aot` to run the application. When the build is finished and I run ng serve for the first time, everything works fine and I am able to access the application on the browser. But when I save a file in the library, the build job will be executed and the `ng serve` will run again as usual. But this time, I will get a bunch of errors, which complaints that it Cannot determine the module for the class and this is for all the components that I used in the library.

One of the errors is like the following.

```
Cannot determine the module for class LeaveApplicationViewComponent in /Users/me/Desktop/Work/ng-lib-leave-mgmt/projects/ng-lib-leave-mgmt/src/lib/modules/leave-application/leave-application-view/leave-application-view.component.ts! Add LeaveApplicationViewComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
```

I have a `LeaveApplicationModule` in the library and all these components are included in the `NgModule` section. The code is as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LeaveApplicationRoutingModule } from './leave-application-routing.module';

import { LeaveApplicationCreateCommonComponent } from './leave-application-create-common/leave-application-create-common.component';
import { LeaveApplicationListComponent } from './leave-application-list/leave-application-list.component';
import { LeaveApplicationViewComponent } from './leave-application-view/leave-application-view.component';
import { LeaveMgmtSharedModule } from '../leave-mgmt-shared/leave-mgmt-shared.module';
import { LeaveApplicationListApproverComponent } from './leave-application-list-approver/leave-application-list-approver.component';
import { LeaveApproverListComponent } from './leave-approver-list/leave-approver-list.component';
import { LeaveWorkflowCreateComponent } from './leave-workflow-create/leave-workflow-create.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LeaveApplicationCreateComponent,
    LeaveApplicationCreateCommonComponent,
    LeaveApplicationListComponent,
    LeaveApplicationViewComponent,
    LeaveApplicationListApproverComponent,
    LeaveApproverListComponent,
    LeaveWorkflowCreateComponent
  ],
  imports: [ 
    CommonModule,
    LeaveApplicationRoutingModule,
    LeaveMgmtSharedModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    AutoCompleteModule
  ],
  exports:[
    LeaveApplicationCreateComponent,
    LeaveApplicationCreateCommonComponent,
    LeaveApplicationListComponent,
    LeaveApplicationViewComponent,
    LeaveApplicationListApproverComponent,
    LeaveApproverListComponent,
    LeaveWorkflowCreateComponent
  ],
})
export class LeaveApplicationModule { }
```

I have a few other modules there but the error is with this module only and with the `aot` option. I am not sure what is wrong here. I checked the `casing` of the file names and it seems fine. Anyway, everything works until I make any change and save it. So now I need to stop and re-run `ng serve --aot` every time I make a change to the code and it is very time-consuming activity. It will be really helpful if someone can tell me what is wrong here and how can I fix it.

Comment: Do you have a stackblitz link/sample?

Comment: Actually, it is a large project and when I tried to create the sample, it is working fine. I think this has something to do with the libraries. Can you please share how is the angular library development workflow?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Angular are you using?

Recent versions of angular have aot turned on by default, and so during compilation needs a list of all modules. You might have to add the TimeAgoPipe to your declarations, and import the pipe.

```
import { TimeAgoPipe } from './_pipes/time-ago-pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TimeAgoPipe, ...]
})
```

Use this link for some additional answers if needed : [cannot determine the module for component angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119135/cannot-determine-the-module-for-component-angular-5)

Comment: I am using Angular 8. So AOT is not turned on by default I think

Comment: I am using angular 8 and I have the same error. Did you resolve it ?